# How to save barcode data to TextView

Tags: android, barcode

I have followed a tutorial where I am using Android Studio to make a scanner that will save a QR code to a TextView in Activity_main.xml. So far it works so that when I insert this `{"name":"Gabriel","address":"NoNameStreet"}` in a QR generator site, in the contents of the QR code that will be created, the result is that it will set the name and adress textview on my app after I scan the QR code, like this.

[image]

But when I want to add the same contents on a Barcode generator site, the generator doesn't allow me to use some the characters like "," or "{". Does anyone now how I can generate a Barcode to get the same results or if I would have to modify my code somehow to fix it?
Here is the code I am using in the MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.androidscanner2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textViewName, textViewAddress;

    private IntentIntegrator qrScan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewAddress= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAddress);

        qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    }

    public void scanQRCode(View view) {
        qrScan.initiateScan();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result != null) {
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Result not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());
                    textViewName.setText(obj.getString("name"));
                    textViewAddress.setText(obj.getString("address"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }else{
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okey then! So should I just use Android, for Android related programming?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. You can also read the tag wikis (they show up when you start typing it, or you can find it at `https://stackoverflow.com/tags/some-tag-name/info`) for additional usage guidance - most tags have them.